# python cast object to int

Tags: python, object, casting, integer

I am using the numpy module to retrieve the position of the maximum value in a 2d array. But this 2d array consists of MyObjects. Now I get the error:

> TypeError: unorderable types: int() > MyObject()

I tried to override the int function with this code:

```
def int(self):
    return self.score
```

But this does not solve my problem.
Do I have to convert my 2d array of MyObjects into a 2d array of integers, do I have to extend the Integer object (if this is possible in python) or can I override this int() function in another way?

[EDIT]

The full object:

```
class MyObject:
def __init__(self, x, y, score, direction, match):
    self.x = x
    self.y = y
    self.score = score
    self.direction = direction
    self.match = match

def __str__(self):
    return str(self.score)

def int(self):
    return self.score
```

The way I call this object:

```
 def traceBack(self):
    self.matrix = np.array(self.matrix)
    maxIndex = self.matrix.argmax()
    print(self.matrix.unravel_index(maxIndex))
```

Comment: Please post all related code in `MyObject`, and you'll get help much easier. What is `self.score`?

Comment: What do you expect the maximum value of your array to be, if it doesn't contain `float` or `int` data types?

Comment: That's not even how you're meant to override conversion to integer... Hint: it's [`__int__()`](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__int__), and whatever you're doing probably isn't going to call it anyway - I don't believe Python attempts to coerce objects to the same type when comparing them.

Comment: `str(self.score)` is not an int...

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Try to use

```
...
def __int__(self):
    return self.score
...

test = MyObject(0, 0, 10, 0, 0)
print 10+int(test)

# Will output: 20
```

in your MyObject class definition.

Comment: Just checked, `__int__(self)` will work well. use `int(MyObject)` casting method to convert your object to integer.

Answer (score 1):

The `max` function takes a `key` that is applied on the elements. that's where you put `score`

Typically :

```
a = max(my_list, key=score)
```

Comment: That will give you a NameError on score.  You need to use a getter, something like `lambda s: s.score` (or `operator.attrgetter("score")`).